# Firefox Add-on SDK error

Tags: python, windows, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to launch:`cfx run`but I'm getting following error:

```
(C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14) C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\my-addon>cfx run
Using binary at 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'.
Using profile at 'c:\users\michal~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpkcrwv7.mozrunner'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\bin\cfx", line 33, in <module>
    cuddlefish.run()
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\__init__.py", line 928, in run
    bundle_sdk=options.bundle_sdk)
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 706, in run_app
    runner.start()
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\mozrunner\__init__.py", line 529, in start
    self.process_handler = run_command(self.command+self.cmdargs, self.env, **self.kp_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\mozrunner\__init__.py", line 59, in run_command
    return killableprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env, **killable_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
TypeError: _execute_child() takes exactly 17 arguments (18 given)
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 534, in maybe_remove_outfile
    os.remove(outfile)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\michal~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\harness-stdout-l8remz'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "C:\Users\michal smoczyk\Downloads\addon-sdk-1.14\python-lib\cuddlefish\runner.py", line 534, in maybe_remove_outfile
    os.remove(outfile)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\\users\\michal~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\harness-stdout-l8remz'
```

My Firefox version: 26. I've installed Python 2.7. OS: Windows Vista, SDK: 1.14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest getting the latest version of the SDK (`addon-sdk-1.15.zip`) from the [Mozilla Developer Hub :: Add-ons for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) web page. Also make sure to read an follow the instructions in the README file that comes with it (if you haven't already).

One pertinent thing it says is:

> If you get an error when running cfx or have any other problems
>   getting started, see the "Troubleshooting" guide at:
>   https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/troubleshooting.html

Comment: It didn't work but the add-on builder suits me very well. THX!

Answer (score 7):

The current 1.15 version of the Add-on SDK seems to be incomaptible with Python 2.7.6.

I got the same error and downgraded to Python 2.7.5 to solve this issue.

Here are some relevant bug reports:
[Bug 950894 - [mozprocess] TypeError under windows evironment in cpython 2.7.6](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=950894) 
[Bug 958609 - Add-on SDK 1.15 incompatible with Python 2.7.6](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=958609)

---

Update: [The bug has been fixed](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/pull/1379).

Answer (score 0):

try to install add-on sdk 1.15 with python 2.6.6 then do this steps

1-  Download [cp720](http://blog.oneortheother.info/wp-content/uploads/2007/11/cp720.zip)

2-  unzip the zip file.

3-  Copy or Move the file cp720.py into your python encodings folder.

```
 Example: C:\Python26\Lib\encodings\
```